# Swift Charts xAxis Label Alignment

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

Fully aware this question has been asked multiple times, but I've tried as many solutions as I can find with no meaningful result.  Here's the issue where the dates don't match up with their data groupings.  There are the same number of both items:

[image]

The X date values are being compiled dynamically based on the age on the database entries.  Code below:

```
var allDiaperEntries: [SubmittedEntry] = []
    var allDiaperDates: [Date] = []
    daysUnformatted = []
    days = []

    for diaper in realm.objects(SubmittedEntry.self).filter("diaperIsWet = true or diaperIsPoopy = true or diaperIsCombo = true") {
        allDiaperEntries.append(diaper)
    }

    for diaper in allDiaperEntries {
        allDiaperDates.append(diaper.submissionTime!)
    }

    allDiaperDates.sort(by: { $0 < $1 })


    let oldestDiaperEntry = allDiaperDates.first

    var dateToCheck = Date()

    let calendar = Calendar.current

    repeat {

        dateToCheck = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: dateToCheck)!
        daysUnformatted.append(dateToCheck)

    } while !calendar.isDate(dateToCheck, inSameDayAs: oldestDiaperEntry!)

    daysUnformatted.insert(Date(), at: daysUnformatted.startIndex)


    let daysDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    daysDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    for day in daysUnformatted {
        daysDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
        days.append(daysDateFormatter.string(from: day))
    }
    days.reverse()
}
```

And then I build the chart in:

```
buildDiaperDays()

    barView.noDataText = "Charts will be available after submitting baby events."
    var dataEntriesWet: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    var dataEntriesPoopy: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    var dataEntriesCombo: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<days.count {
        let dataEntryWet = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: diaperCountsWet[i], data: days[i] as AnyObject)
        dataEntriesWet.append(dataEntryWet)

        let dataEntryPoopy = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: diaperCountsPoopy[i], data: days[i] as AnyObject)
        dataEntriesPoopy.append(dataEntryPoopy)

        let dataEntryCombo = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: diaperCountsCombo[i], data: days[i] as AnyObject)
        dataEntriesCombo.append(dataEntryCombo)
    }

    let chartDataSetWet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntriesWet, label: "Wet Diapers")
    let chartDataSetPoopy = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntriesPoopy, label: "Poopy Diapers")
    let chartDataSetCombo = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntriesCombo, label: "Combo Diapers")

    let dataSets: [BarChartDataSet] = [chartDataSetWet, chartDataSetPoopy, chartDataSetCombo]

    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: dataSets)

    let groupSpace = 0.3
    let barSpace = 0.05
    let barWidth = 0.3

    let groupCount = self.days.count
    let startYear = 0

    barView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:days)
    barView.xAxis.granularity = 1
    barView.xAxis.labelCount = days.count
    barView.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 270

    chartData.barWidth = barWidth;
    barView.xAxis.axisMinimum = Double(startYear)
    let gg = chartData.groupWidth(groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)
    barView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(startYear) + gg * Double(groupCount)

    chartData.groupBars(fromX: Double(startYear), groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)

    barView.notifyDataSetChanged()

    barView.data = chartData

    barView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 189/255, green: 195/255, blue: 199/255, alpha: 0)

    barView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.5, yAxisDuration: 1.5, easingOption: .easeInSine)
```

Appreciate the community's assistance.

Comment: I count six groupings but more than six dates. Are you trying to only get dates displayed (and aligned) for the groupings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
barView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
barView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
```

Need to change the below values:

```
let groupSpace = 0.1
let barSpace = 0.05
let barWidth = 0.25
// (barWidth + barSpace) * (no.of.bars) + groupSpace = 1.00 -> interval per "group"
```

Comment: They moved to the bottom (as expected) but no other change.

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates? Or can you please explain what exactly you need?

Comment: There are the same number of dates as there are groupings, but the dates aren't aligning to the groupings.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check whether it will work for you or not.

Comment: Still no change.  In the original code have have the granularity set to `1`.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data of `days`?

Comment: `["Aug 16, 2017", "Aug 17, 2017", "Aug 18, 2017", "Aug 19, 2017", "Aug 20, 2017", "Aug 21, 2017", "Aug 22, 2017", "Aug 23, 2017", "Aug 24, 2017", "Aug 25, 2017", "Aug 26, 2017", "Aug 27, 2017", "Aug 28, 2017", "Aug 29, 2017"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153174/discussion-between-vini-app-and-fasterthanllamas).

Comment: Updated answer. Please check